Cannot Convert to Correct Number Format SQL Server
Data was transfer from float datatype column in one table to varchar(50) type column in another table and number are converted into exponential format. How to convert back to pure numbers
2.02403e+015
2.02404e+015
2.02404e+015
2.02402e+015


Do you still have access to the original float column? Why was it converted to varchar() in the first place?

Perhaps the real problem is you were using float to start with, and the second is you are now using a varchar. Surely a decimal would be a more appropriate data type, no?

@HardCode no data is converted so i dont have access to float column

I suggest you ALTER the column to a float and then a decimal/numerical with an appropriate precision and scale. I just hope your original value was 2024030000000000.

Can you pls share some query sample

How do you change the datatype of a column in SQL Server?

I cannot alter real table, is it possible with temp table

Does this answer your question? Casting Scientific Notation (from varchar -> numeric) in a view

Then the value you have is correct, @sgl . '2.02403e+015' is the correct varchar representation of that float value. If you don't want that, don't use float or varchar.

If that's all the data you have left, you're smoked, since the details are lost in the rounding. If there's no rounding, just cast it to float and then to numeric

If those were converted from double-precision values you should have had fifteen digits of precision coming across. So presumably most of the lost digits are zeroes except for possibly of the final digit. What is the actual type at the source?

float @shawnt00

@sgl float(53)?

Try the following code to convert exponential value to a decimal value
SELECT convert(numeric(38,0),cast('2.02403e+015' AS float))

